# Technology tags on GitHub-imported projects on the CV aren't displayed

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently note that when I import a project from [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) the technology is correctly detected (I suppose by importing the languages detected by GitHub) as I can see it when I click on the edit project.

However, it is not displayed on the CV in the general view. Is this the expected behavior? As I would expect to display and use the language it detected. Does it affect when performing search from the employer point of view?

Sorry, I don't have image with [red hand-drawn circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).